# Function is returning `Future[Option[Boolean]]` how should i destructure it to check boolean?

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous

Problem is suppose there is a function `xyz()` which has a return type of `Future[Some[Boolean]]` Now what i want is that I want to trigger a function `abc()` whenever this boolean value is true I am not sure how to destructure it in scala . What I have tried is

```
val ans = xyz()
ans.map((itr)=>{
      itr match{
          Some(true)=> abc()
   }
})
```

I could be completely wrong too , I don't know much about futures please recommend any easy to understand documentation for futures too and also please explain what is tecnique to destructure a future value a `map` function something or `flatmap` because I have seen them used frequently

Answer (score 4):

A `Future` represents a value that might not have been computed yet.  Until there's a value, there's nothing to destructure.

The simplest, though non-deterministic, way to check the value of a `Future` is via the `value` method, which (in your case) would project it to an `Option[Try[Option[Boolean]]]`, with values interpreted as:

- `None` means that the future has not yet completed and thus has no value
- `Some(Failure(exception))` means that the future completed with a failure and the failure is elaborated as `exception`
- `Some(Success(None))` means the future completed with `None`
- `Some(Success(Some(true)))` means the future completed with `Some(true)`
- `Some(Success(Some(false)))` means the future completed with `Some(false)`

As noted, this is non-deterministic, though once the `value` transitions from `None` to `Some`, it will stay that way, so you could use a while-loop to check `value`.

That said, you'd get the same result, without wasting CPU, by blocking using `Await.result(future, someDurationToWait)`.  This will throw the exception if the future fails and otherwise you'd get an `Option[Boolean]` with the result.

That approach has the downside of blocking a thread, which is a finite resource and, done too often, can lead to deadlock.  So you should really only be doing `Await.result` in the outermost layer of your program, or in places where you absolutely must present a blocking API.

The most idiomatic thing in Scala is to schedule callbacks to be executed in response to the future completing with a value.  There are four main ways to schedule a callback, and eachof these requires that you specify an `ExecutionContext` in which the callback will be executed (selection of a proper `ExecutionContext` is outside of the scope of this answer):

- `filter`: passes a failed future through unchanged and turns a succeeded future into a failed future unless some predicate is met.

```scala
val fut: Future[Option[Boolean]] = ???
// assuming that fut completes, transformed will only be failed or succeed with `Some(true)`
val transformed: Future[Option[Boolean]] =
  fut.filter(_.contains(true))
```

- `foreach`: if the future is successful, will pass the result to a function called for side-effect:

```scala
val fut: Future[Option[Boolean]] = ???
// will print Some(false) or Some(true) or None if the future completes, otherwise nothing will ever print
fut.foreach(println _)
```

- `map`: passes through a failed future and transforms the value of a successful future

```scala
val fut: Future[Option[Boolean]] = ???
def f(x: Option[Boolean]): Int =
  x match {
    case None => 0
    case Some(false) => 1
    case Some(true) => 2
  }

val transformed: Future[Int] = fut.map(f)
```

- `flatMap`: lets you transform a future with transformation that results in another future

```scala
val fut: Future[Option[Boolean]] = ???
def callAnotherApi(): Future[Int] = ???

def f(x: Option[Boolean]): Future[Int] =
  x match {
    case None => Future.failed(new IllegalArgumentException("don't know"))
    case Some(false) => Future.successful(1)
    case Some(true) => callAnotherApi()
  }

fut.flatMap(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend getting familiar with matching syntax, or use some some IDE. There are several ways you can achieve this e.g.

```
ans.map {
  // case is necessary when you ar matching
  case Some(true) => abc()
  // handle all the cases, even if you need a wildcard
  case _ => // otherwise
}
```

They are obvious if you completed something like Coursera or other free tutorial.

Comment: This one give a error I tried with this method , it says , Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type, found: Some[A], required: Future[Option[Boolean]]
note I considered `ans` of type `Future[Option[Boolean]]`

Comment: I believe you used `match` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an overkill in this case, but I would recommend using [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) for working with `Future[Option[T]]`:

```
val ans = OptionT(xyz())
ans.collect {
  case true => abc()
}
```

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5tnWZ4MnQQ2MKMZPVLheAg